# Why is the stalk cohomology of the nearby cycles of a sheaf complex exactly the hypercohomology of the Milnor fiber of that complex?

Tags: fiber-bundles

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $f\colon X\to\mathbb{C}$ a non-constant holomorphic map. We define $X_t=f^{-1}(t)$. Let $\mathcal{F}^\bullet\in D^b(X)$ and we denote by $\psi_f$ the nearby cycle functor and by $F_x$ the Milnor fiber of $f$ at $x$.

Recall the definition of the nearby cycle functor:
Consider the cartesian square (sry for the bad style)
\begin{align}
& \ \ \tilde{X^*} \longrightarrow \tilde{\mathbb{C}^*}\\
& \tilde{p}\downarrow\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \downarrow p\\
X_0 \overset{i}{\longrightarrow} & \ \ \ \ X \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{C}
\end{align}
where $p$ is the universal covering of $\mathbb{C}^*$ embedded in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\tilde{X^*}$  the usual pullback. We define $\psi_f=i^{-1}R\tilde{p}_*\tilde{p}^{-1}$.

I want to show that for all points $x\in X_0$ there is a natural isomorphism $\mathscr{H}^k(\psi_f\mathcal{F}^\bullet)_x\simeq\mathbb{H}^k(F_x,\mathcal{F}^\bullet)$.

I am currently reading

*Dimca, Alexandru*, Sheaves in topology, Universitext. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-20665-5/pbk). xvi, 236 p. (2004). [ZBL1043.14003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1043.14003).

This result is precisely Proposition 4.2.2. in the book and it says that this can be obtained by direct computation. I tried to do it but I am stuck at one point. Here is what I got until now.

\begin{align}
\mathscr{H}^k(\psi_f\mathcal{F}^\bullet)_x & \simeq H^k((\psi_f\mathcal{F}^\bullet)_x)\\
& \simeq H^k((R\tilde{p}_*\tilde{p}^{-1}\mathcal{F}^\bullet)_{i(x)=x})\\
& \simeq H^k(\underset{\underset{x\in U}{\longrightarrow}}{\text{lim}}R\Gamma(U,R\tilde{p}_*\tilde{p}^{-1}\mathcal{F}^\bullet))\\
& \simeq \underset{\underset{x\in U}{\longrightarrow}}{\text{lim}} \mathbb{H}^k(U,R\tilde{p}_*\tilde{p}^{-1}\mathcal{F}^\bullet)\\
& \simeq \underset{\underset{x\in U}{\longrightarrow}}{\text{lim}}\mathbb{H}^k(\tilde{p}^{-1}(U),\tilde{p}^{-1}\mathcal{F}^\bullet)
\end{align}
Is this even the right way to approach this? Is it okay to pull the limit out of the cohomology?

Answer (score 1):

It seems common for everyone to simply state that the stalk of the nearby cycle is the cohomology of the Milnor fibre and leave it at that. I remember thinking once upon a time that this wasn't obvious, so let me try to write an answer. I will add some extra notation: Let $X_\eta$ denote the complement of $X_0$ in $X$, and $j:X_\eta\to X$ be the inclusion. Write $\pi:\tilde{X_\eta}\to X_\eta$ to be the pullback of the universal cover of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ under $f$. Then $\psi_f=i^\ast j_\ast \pi_\ast \pi^\ast j^\ast$ is the definition of the nearby cycle.

Let's start by mentioning the assumptions on $\mathcal{F}$. We need $\mathcal{F}$ to be constructible. We will also need the geometry of nearby fibres: If $x\in X_0$, then for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, the ball $B_\epsilon (x)$ of radius $\epsilon$ about $x$ has the property that for $\delta$ sufficiently small (compared to epsilon), the map $f$, restricted to $B_\epsilon(x)$, is a fibration over $\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid 0<|z|<\delta\}$ (Milnor-Le fibration).  This will be our nontrivial geometric input. Now choose a stratification for which $\mathcal{F}$ is stratified, and choose $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ such that the above fibration result holds for the restriction of $f$ to every stratum in our stratification. This is possible since the stratification is finite.

Inside this fibration, we obtain an isomorphism between the Milnor fibre $F_x$ and any fibre, and the restriction of $\mathcal{F}$ to any of these fibres "looks the same". (So the cohomology of $F_x$ with coefficients in $\mathcal{F}$ is well-defined).

In the task at hand, we want to compute a stalk of $\psi_f\mathcal{F}$, which means computing the sections of $\psi_f\mathcal{F}$ in a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $x$. The presence of the $i^\ast j_\ast$ factors means that we have to compute the sections of $\pi_\ast\pi^\ast j^\ast \mathcal{F}$ in the intersection of $X_\eta$ with a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $x$.

Now let's turn our attention to the push-pull piece of the construction. Ultimately we will see that this is a contrivance designed to not favour any particular nearby fibre, and its presence is needed in the definition because the base $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is not simply-connected. The relevant fact for our computation is that $\pi$ is a Galois cover, being a pullback of a Galois cover. Let $U$ be a sufficiently small open set in $X_\eta$, so that $\pi^{-1}U\cong \sqcup_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} \tau^i(V)$, where $\pi$ induces a homeomorphism from $V$ to $U$, and $\tau$ is a generator of $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}^\times)$ acting by deck transformations. Then we have $$(\pi_\ast\pi^{\ast}(j^\ast \mathcal{F}))(U)\cong \prod_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} (j^{\ast}\mathcal{F})(U)$$
with each factor coming from one piece in the fibre, and the monodromy group acting by permuting the factors.

We're interested in sections of $\pi_\ast\pi^{\ast}j^\ast \mathcal{F}$ in a small-enough neighbourhood that is a neighbourhood of the central fibre. We assume our neighbourhood is small enough so that $f$ is a fibration in this neighbourhood for all strata relevant to $\mathcal{F}$, which implies $j^\ast \mathcal{F}$ is locally constant. When we take a local section and transport it by a loop around the central fibre, in the interpretation of the section as an element of a product, the component in each factor is shifted (by the indexing $i\mapsto i+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$). So the component of a local section in a single factor completely determines, and is determined by, a global section.

A local section, over a disk in $\mathbb{C}^\ast$ is precisely the cohomology of the Milnor fibre with coefficients in $\mathcal{F}$, due to $f$ being a fibration here and the disk being contractible. In this way we obtain the desired result, that the stalk of the nearby cycle is the cohomology of the Milnor fibre.

Comment: Dear Peter, thank you for your answer. I found it helpful. May I ask why it matters that $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is not simply-connected? I guess I still don't understand why we need to pass to the universal cover in the definition of the vanishing cycle. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Marielle. Consider a small loop around the origin. Follow the Milnor fibre around this loop until we return to the starting place. We obtain an endomorphism of the cohomology of the Milnor fibre, that is usually not the identity (e.g. f:C->C, f(z)=z^n). The existence of this monodromy action is ultimately why the passage to the universal cover is needed (or something else that achieves similar results, like looking at vanishing cycles at angle theta). Without the passage to the universal cover, we would instead be taking invariants of this monodromy action.